# How to use the human body as a battery?

Tags: led, batteries, 3.3v

I was wondering if you'd be able to extract 5 volts (or even just 3) from the human body. I recently discovered in an experiment that just putting a wet strip of aluminum foil over your forehead can produce about half a volt. I was wondering if I could take this one step further and get enough energy to power an LED. I also noticed that the place on your skin that produces the most voltage is your forehead. Where else could I put foil? And would, all of it combined, produce 3.3 volts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be a one-word comment but it has a minimum character count so I'm complaining about that in addition to just saying: No.

Comment: put the foil on various places ... report back with your findings

Comment: The impedance of the skin-electrode interface is pretty high, making it hard to get much current. However, if you don’t mind  electrodes inside yourself, the impedance is much less. Electricity in your body is mostly generated chemically, by your nerves. Probably the power you could extract is small, but perhaps enough to run very low power electronic stuff. Do some googling.

Comment: shades of Matrix? ... lol

Comment: The Energizer bunny walks around with 3 volts strapped to his back.

Comment: If you find a way congratulations because then it would be a calorie burner while you are asleep and you'd become a millionaire within weeks - new product - slim whilst sleeping or watching TV.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you. Good luck researching 

Comment: I believe significant current might be generated by a tightly fitting foil cap on a shaved head combined with a copper tongue depressor or other medical dubisary. The voltage will be limited for a single cell, but with enough current, a Joule thief might provide sufficient voltage to power a radio receiver to monitor alien communications.

Comment: To get to that sort of voltage you'd need to cut it into pieces and connect them in series.

Answer (score 4):

This seems more like a question for one of the stack exchange science networks, like physics or chemistry.
Also the best way to generate more voltage would be either through static electricity or, as someone else commented, accessing the electricity generated by your nerves through internal electrodes. I do not recommend the second option since it could be dangerous and painful. Through personal experience accessing the electricity in nerves involves having small needles in your muscles which is not to fun.